# Laravel Numbers Only Validation

Tags: validation, laravel

How to validate only numbers in laravel?
I've try numeric and digits but it accept + and - character as a valid numbers / digits which I don't want. (+123 or -123 is validated as valid numeric)

Is there a existing rule on laravel that only accept 0-9 as a valid numbers or I have to go with regex instead?

Comment: You could do integer

Comment: @tam It's still accept + and - and cannot use 0 at front. (0123) is not valid

Comment: Oh right. Well ya I think u gotta use regex bc the PHP function is_numeric allows for the sign, it's a very simple regex though

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I end up using regex instead.

```
regex:/^[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

try this rule :

```
digits_between:min,max
```

it only allows numbers, you just need to specify the min and max number of digits.
exemple:

```
'CowsNumber' => 'digits_between:3,10',
```